# How to replace a text line by searching with '=' symbol in a file using .bat script?

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, find

## How to replace a text line by searching with '=' symbol in a file using .bat script ?

I have a text file test.txt with text as

=================================================

```
PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Think\Digit\Trunk.exe 

WORD=C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft\Word12\Word.exe
```

=================================================

I am able to replace the text "C:\ProgramFiles\Think\Digit\Trunk.exe" with the word, "Deleted"..........

But, i want to replace the entire line by searching as............PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Think\Digit\Trunk.exe.......using the variable SEARCHTEXT. But, i am unable to search with the '=' operator.

## I have the batch file with the following code:-

==================================================================================

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set INTEXTFILE=C:\Users\PrasanthReddy\Desktop\test.txt

set OUTTEXTFILE=C:\Users\PrasanthReddy\Desktop\testsimple.txt

set SEARCHTEXT=C:\ProgramFiles\Think\Digit\Trunk.exe

set REPLACETEXT=Deleted

set OUTPUTLINE=


for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (

   SET string=%%A

   for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ("!string!") do set "string=%%b"

   if  "!string!" == "" (

       echo.>>%OUTTEXTFILE%

   ) else (

      SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

      echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%

  )

)

del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

===========================================================================

Can any one help me how to replace it.....How can i do it....

Comment: regular expressions? or escape the character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of output the string with the replaced value, determine if the replacement has been done and, depending on the result, echo the adecuated value

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "INTEXTFILE=C:\Users\PrasanthReddy\Desktop\test.txt"
    set "OUTTEXTFILE=C:\Users\PrasanthReddy\Desktop\testsimple.txt"

    set "SEARCHTEXT=C:\ProgramFiles\Think\Digit\Trunk.exe"
    set "REPLACETEXT=Deleted"

    (   for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%INTEXTFILE%"'
        ) do if "%%b"=="" (
            echo(
        ) else (
            set "string=%%b"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if "!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=!"=="!string!" (
                endlocal
                echo(%%b
            ) else (
                endlocal
                echo(%REPLACETEXT%
            )
        )
    ) > "%OUTTEXTFILE%"

    move /y "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
```